# CollapsingToolbarLayout setTitle() doesn't work after activity created

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my activity I've created a method for the fragments to update the title :

```
public void setTitle(String title) {
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        if (title == null) {
            title = getString(R.string.string_title);
        }
        ab.setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

The toolbar is part of a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.
It looks like the title is set correctly for the first fragment, however, when the second one tries to update it, it doesn't get updated.
I'm running with v 23 so this is not [the known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175808#c8).